# power analysis for cross-lagged panel model with random intercept using powRICLPM

Tags: r, statistical-power, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I want to compute power analysis for cross-lagged panel model with random intercept using powRICLPM package ([Related publication](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10705511.2022.2122467))

Authors of the package did a great job and the power analysis seems to be quite straightforward. However, it is not explained how to estimate the `Phi` matrix.

`Phi` refers to a matrix of lagged effects

- diagonal: standardized autoregressive effects
- off-diagonal: cross-lagged effects

How to estimate these effects, when the data was not collected yet? Is it done based on previous literature?

I attached code snippet to reproduce the power analysis with made-up `Phi`:

```
library(powRICLPM)
library(progressr)
library(future)

Phi = matrix(c(0.5, -0.2, 
               -0.1, 0.6), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
check_Phi(Phi)

out_preliminary <- with_progress({powRICLPM(
  target_power = 0.8, # desired power
  search_lower = 100, # start estimating power at n = 100
  search_upper = 1000, # end at n = 1000
  search_step = 100, # in n = 100 steps
  time_points = c(3), # 3 time points
  ICC = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6), # test different ICC
  RI_cor = 0.3, # correlation between random intercepts
  Phi = Phi,
  within_cor = 0.2,
  reps = 100, # 100 simulations
  seed = 1234
  )
})

# Create basic plot of powRICLPM object
p <- plot(out_preliminary, parameter = "wB2~wA1")
# Adjust plot aesthetics
p2 <- p + 
  ggplot2::labs(
    title = "Power analysis for RI-CLPM",
    caption = "Based on 100 replications."
  ) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Sample size",
    breaks = seq(100, 1000, 100),
    guide = ggplot2::guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)
  )
p2
```